# Get all img tags and add <a href=""/> between

Tags: php, dom, drupal, simple-html-dom

I want to get all `img` tags from drupal site and then add `a tag` between.

I try the below:

```
 $html_img = new simple_html_dom();
  // Load HTML from a string.
 $html_img->load($node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
  // Remove all plain text fragments.
  foreach ($html_img->find('img') as $e ) {
    $e = "<a href='$node_url'>$e</a>";
  }
```

With above code I take all img tags from drupal but the `$e = "<a href='$node_url'>$e</a>";` doesn't put a link to img tags.

Comment: Can you please post code of what you are having problems with so we can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $img) {
    echo "<a href='#'>$img</a>";
}
```

[DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Was the first result in Google.